# Javascript Element.getBoundingClientRect() return wrong when direct children of element has top/bottom margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id='el1'>
   <div class='directChildren' style='width:50%;height:100px;float:left;margin-top:0'>
    ....
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id='el2'>
   <div class='directChildren' style='width:50%;height:100px;float:right;margin-top:20px'>
    ....
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style='clear:both'/>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
const topEl1 = document.getElementById("el1").getBoundingClientRect().top; // return 0 (only example)
const topEl2 = document.getElementById("el2").getBoundingClientRect().top; // return 20 (topEl1 + margin top of el2)
```

**QUESTION:**
Both of divs (el1, el2) has same top coordinate but why getBoundingClientRect return different ?. This case also happen for margin-bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the CSS is not properly defined. You are using **float** on inner element(**.directChildren**) instead of using it on **#el1 and #el2** without properly clearing float behavior on parent elements. That is why the effect of **margin-top** is overflowing the parent's dimension.

It is much easier to achieve the correct result by using following HTML and CSS where I have used proper styling by using **flex**. You can also use **float** if you want.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id='el1'>
    <div class='directChildren' style='height:100px;margin-top:0'>
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='el2'>
    <div class='directChildren' style='height:100px;margin-top:20px'>
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container .directChildren {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: I'am sory, the code has been edited, please review again. That was what i mean before.

Comment: @Kardinata Please don't change a question after it has been answered as this invalidates the answer. Ask a new follow-up question instead. I will roll back the question to its original version.